# React-Native: read timestamp saved on Firebase, after updating it

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, getdate

I update a **timestamp** in a **Firebase** server every time I click a button on my react-native app (android).
The problem is that, *after updating it*, I want to **read it** and set my state with this timestamp.

Here is some code I found on the Internet, it updates the date on **Firebase**, reach the first **'then' block** but then never go on, so never reach the second **'then' block** and never show the **alert(onlyDate);**

I have no error about **rules** on Firebase, read and write are both available.

```js
getDateServerFirebase = () => {

    let fb_currentTime = firebase.database().ref('currentTime/');
    fb_currentTime.update({ time: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP })
    .then(() => {
      fb_currentTime.once('value').then(function (data) {
          //console.log(data);
          let timestamp = data._value.time;
          let fullDate = new Date(timestamp);
          let onlyDate = fullDate.getDate() + '/' + (fullDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + fullDate.getFullYear();

          alert(onlyDate);

        }, function serverTimeErr(err) {
          console.log('Could not reach to the server time !');
        });
    }, function (err) {
      console.log ('set time error:', err)
    });
  }
```

I tried this and still the same problem: *writing works, reading not*.

```js
setData = () =>{
    firebase.database().ref('prova/').set({
      name:'luis',
      surname:'rew'
    }, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        // The write failed...
      } else {
        // Data saved successfully!
      }
    });
  }

  readData = () =>{
    firebase.database().ref('prova/')
    .once('value')
    .then((data)=>{
      alert(data);
    })
  }
```

Can someone help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you access response from firebase function is through running the val(); function on the result.

change this line

```
let timestamp = data._value.time;
```

into this:

```
let timestamp = data.val().time;
```

Comment: It works, but after some attempts, after reading many times the value error occur again :(

Comment: Can you explain more what do you mean by 'many times' and which error exactly occur?

Comment: After reloding the app, clicking the button does not show more the alert.

Comment: Probably related to communication issue with firebase, try to give more details about the error you receive...